# Foot pedals as modifier keys for Mac

Tags: macos, keyboard, accessibility

I am hoping to buy a couple of foot pedals that I could use as `Ctrl` and `Shift` for my MacBook Pro. Is this at all **possible** with an OS X machine? I have read that Kinesis foot pedals (e.g. [this one](http://www.kinesis-ergo.com/shop/savant-elite-module-pedal/)) **cannot** be used as modifiers in combination with other keyboards. Is this correct? If so, why?

Comment: Apparently the other option is Karbriner: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/7remed/has_anybody_used_foot_pedals/dw462sj/ I wish I knew whether this will work or not before I spend $180 on an online purchase.

Comment: Karabiner works for me as you would expect on Mojave

Answer (score 3):

I created my own "keyboard combiner". It lets me use the Kinesis Savant Elite Triple Foot Pedals for shift, alt, and command modifiers on a Mac.

https://github.com/davidbkemp/KeyboardCombinerArduinoSketch/wiki

It is quite easy to assemble, but I cannot guarantee that it will work for you. It certainly does not work with some pedals and some keyboards.  For the Kinesis pedals, you will initially need to configure them to act as shift, alt, and command keys, and that means using a PC to do the initial configuration.

Comment: I think (newer versions of?) the Kinesis pedal configuration allow you to specify the basic bindings without a PC.

Comment: NOTE: you need an Adruino / Raspberry Pi for this. Having had a negative experience with Raspberry Pi I'm not so motivated by this. Though I applaud the endeavour.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely possible, there's this great *ControllerMate* software that lets you assign keys and keyboard shortcuts to various pedals. Take a look at the following SuperUser answer: https://superuser.com/a/1486751